# How to read data from a file in a difficult format?

Tags: python, matrix

I have output data from a file that I need to read. It is a matrix but it's laid out in a difficult manner in the output file. See below - this is a 5x5 matrix but only the non-zero elements are printed:

```
SCATTER MOMENT      1

GROUP      1 FIRST      1 LAST    5
  1.000000E-00  2.000000E-00  3.000000E-00  4.000000E-00  5.000000E-00
GROUP      2 FIRST      2 LAST    5
  2.000000E-00  3.000000E-00  4.000000E-00  5.000000E-00
GROUP      3 FIRST      3 LAST    4
  3.000000E-00  4.000000E-00
GROUP      4 FIRST      4 LAST    5
  4.000000E-00  5.000000E-00
GROUP      5 FIRST      3 LAST    5
  3.000000E-00  4.000000E-00  5.000000E-00
  
SCATTER MOMENT      2
```

So this should be this matrix, adding in the non-printed zeroes:

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 2 3 4 5
0 0 3 4 0
0 0 0 4 5
0 0 3 4 5
```

I need to write a Python script that will:

1. Search for "SCATTER MOMENT 1" as the data start point identifier
2. Create and populate a matrix, reading data from the FIRST to the LAST group and inserting zeroes everywhere else
3. Do this for every GROUP

Although this example is 5x5, the matrix can be any shape. So far I only have the search for the start identifier, any pointers on reading in the data would be greatly appreciated.

```
start_identifier = "SCATTER MOMENT      1"
end_identifier = "SCATTER MOMENT      2"

def read_data_from_file(file_name, start_identifier, end_identifier):
    list_of_results = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
            t=f.read()
    t=t[t.find(start_identifier)+len(start_identifier):t.find(end_identifier)]
            t=t.replace('\n', '').split()
            t=[float(i) for i in t if not i.isidentifier()]
            list_of_results.extend(t)
    return(list_of_results)
```

I previously posted this question but have re-worded it and included a better example of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using regular expressions to match the lines containing the group information as well as extract the values in them needed. Since you won't know the dimensions of the matrix until all the lines of data have been read, a post-processing step is needed to lengthen any rows that are too short.

```
import re

group_pattern = re.compile(r"GROUP +\d+ FIRST +(?P<first>\d+) LAST +(?P<last>\d+)")

def read_data_from_file(file_name):
    results = []
    longest = 0
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for line in file:
            match = group_pattern.search(line)
            if match:
                first = int(match.group('first'))
                last = int(match.group('last'))
                data = [float(value) for value in next(file).split()]
                row = [0.0] * last
                for i, value in enumerate(data, start=first-1):
                    row[i] = value
                longest = max(longest, len(row))
                results.append(row)

    for row in results:
        if len(row) < longest:
            row.extend([0.0] * (longest-len(row)))
    return results

results = read_data_from_file('difficult-format.dat')
for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Printed results:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: This works great on the example but not on my full data file - I get a 'list assignment index out of range' error at row[i] = value for some reason? The only difference is that the full data file has 172 groups, but the syntax is the same everywhere else?

Comment: That error sounds like the `row = [0.0] * last`, which pre-allocates the list, was wrong — perhaps the data in the file is wrong for that row (i.e. the value for LAST in incorrect). You should be able to debug this. If not, add the lines causing the problem to the example in your question (and let me know).

Comment: Is the regex very sensitive to the number of columns (spaces and numbers) after "LAST"? It is failing on the first line, which is "GROUP      1 FIRST      1 LAST    163", and the issue is that it thinks the length of that row is 3. So I think it is only reading the final digit in 163?

Comment: Yes, that it — a misplaced `+`. See updated answer.

Comment: That's great, thank you! The only issue is that this doesn't stop reading at "SCATTER MOMENT 2" and so it reads the whole file in?

Comment: If reading the whole file is a problem for some reason — it's unclear why it would be — you can easily stop when the end identifier is seen — check for it as the first thing following `for line in file:`.

Comment: Final issue: this only reads in the first line after the group pattern. When I have 172x172 data, it misses out the subsequent lines?

Comment: The code parses the example data in the format shown in your question, where there's only a single line of numeric data following each group line.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work?
I just find the first and last numbers and prepend and append the appropriate number of zeros.

```
def read_data(filename, start="SCATTER MOMENT      1", end="SCATTER MOMENT      2"):
    between = False
    data_next = False
    size = 0
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            if start in line:
                between = True
            elif end in line:
                between = False
            elif line.startswith("GROUP") and between:
                data_next = True
                parts = line.split()
                first = int(parts[3])
                last = int(parts[5])
                if last > size:
                    size = last
            elif data_next  and between:
                data_next = False
                parts = line.split()
                row = [0.0] * (first-1) + list(map(float, parts))
                matrix.append(row)
    for row in matrix:
        if len(row) < size:
            row += [0.0] * (size - len(row))
    return matrix
```

Comment: This works on my test file but, when there is more data after "SCATTER MOMENT      2", it doesn't stop reading and also adds that data?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to use the variable I made to control that. Should work now

Comment: Thanks, that does fix that issue! Final problem: it only reads in the first line of data after the group pattern. When I have 172x172 data, it misses out the subsequent lines. Is there a way to modify this to read from one GROUP keyword until the next?